# how can I add something to a list in a specific spot without using insert

Tags: python

would love some advice please. I am fairly new to programming and am working on an assignment where I need to add something a value into a list in a specified position. The parameters of the assignment are that you have to use a loop, and you cannot use any built in functions other than range() or append().

The error I am getting is that the line 4th from bottom says "TypeError: can only concatenate list (not "int") to list" and I am not sure how to fix this. 
Any advice would be much appreciated! Please note - as this is for an assignment I'm not looking for the code, rather advice on where I am going wrong and how I can fix it as I want to learn and understand!

```
my_list = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 4, 1, 4, 6]

#function 1 - takes list as parameter and returns length
def length(my_list):
    count = 0
    for x in my_list:
        count = count + 1
    return count

#function 5 - returns a copy of the list with the value inserted at the specified pos
def insert_value(my_list, value, insert_position):
    count = 0
    new_list = []
    if insert_position > length(my_list):
        new_list = my_list.append(value)
    elif insert_position < 0:
        new_list = value + my_list
    while count < insert_position:
        new_list = my_list[:insert_position]
        count= count + 1
        new_list = new_list + value
        new_list = new_list[insert_position+1:]
    return new_list
print(insert_value(my_list, 11, 6))
```

Comment: The problem is in expressions like `new_list + value`, where `value` is actually an integer.  To the Python interpreter, adding two lists makes sense, but adding a list and an integer is invalid. When using `+` to concatenate, you’ll have to make a new one-element list containing `value`.

Comment: The line with error is a place where `append()` would be right instead.

Answer (score 2):

You're issue is that you can not add an integer to a list. You can only add two list-like objects together.

So, `new_list = [value] + my_list` for that particular case.

In general, I'd use list slicing. For example:

```
original_list = [0,1,2,3,5,6,7]
value_to_insert = 4
position_to_insert = 4
new_list = original_list[:position_to_insert] + [value_to_insert] + original_list[position_to_insert:]
```

If you have to use a loop:

```
new_list = []
for i in range(length(my_list)):
    new_list.append(my_list[i])
    if i == insert_position:
        new_list.append(my_list(value_to_insert))
return new_list
```

Finally:

```
my_list = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 4, 1, 4, 6]

#function 1 - takes list as parameter and returns length
def length(my_list):
    count = 0
    for x in my_list:
        count = count + 1
    return count

#function 5 - returns a copy of the list with the value inserted at the specified pos
def insert_value(my_list, value, insert_position):
    new_list = []
    for i in range(length(my_list)):
        new_list.append(my_list[i])
        if i == insert_position:
            new_list.append(value)
    return new_list
print(insert_value(my_list, 11, 6))
```

Comment: This looks like a good way to do it but unfortunately I've just looked back over the paramaters and it says no slicing! So now I think my code above is wrong anyway :(

Comment: @bonnsaim my final example does not use any slicing.

Answer (score 0):

As you said in the question, you can use `append()` so instead of `new_list = new_list + value` you should use `new_list.append(value)`

EDIT: Here is a solution without slicing:

```
def insert_value(my_list, value, insert_position):
    new_list = []
    if insert_position > length(my_list):
        new_list = my_list
        new_list.append(value)
    elif insert_position < 0:
        new_list = [value]
        for i in range(length(my_list)):
            new_list.append(my_list[i])
    else:
        for i in range(insert_position):
            new_list.append(my_list[i])
        new_list.append(value)
        for i in range(length(my_list)-insert_position):
            new_list.append(my_list[insert_position+i])
    return new_list
```